# Where is the IE variable stored in html conditional statements?

Tags: javascript, html, web, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I've seen code like

```
<!--[if IE]> ... html tags <![end if]-->
```

I was wondering, where is the IE variable that's looked at stored?
When the browser looks at if IE, which variable is it looking at to check if IE, and can it be accessed somehow?

Comment: It's not a variable per se, just an instruction that Internet Explorer knows how to handle / parse. And no, you cannot use it in a script or anything like that

Comment: I agree with the suggestions given by Phil and Pai.not.pi It is not a variable so you can't access it in any way. IE browser only can understand it so it can execute that code. other browsers will ignore it. Is your overall goal is to identify the IE browser using JS? Please inform us about it. We can try to provide suggestions for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a string value that corresponds to the version of internet explorer being used.

Here are some other values,
[image]

You can read more about the syntax [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Syntax)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But where is it? Is it stored somewhere on the Window object, somewhere internally, or somewhere else?

Comment: @ZackaryF Don't think of them as variables, they're purely string statements that are interpreted by the IE engine. They can't be accessed via code.